# Why ng-options returns Objects in nested json array for country, state, city in Angular.js?

Tags: json, angularjs, select

I'm a Newbie to Angular.js. I'm working with a registration form contains city, state, country select fields which are filtered and displayed via nested json Array using ng-option. Filtering is working good. But I'm getting output like this. Here my console values.

```
city: "Jaipur"
​country: Object { Maharashtra: (4) […], "Madhya Pradesh": (3) […], "$$hashKey": "object:3", … }
​state: Array(3) [ "Jaipur", "Ajmer", "Jodhpur" ]
​<prototype>: {…
```

But I want to retrieve the values of selected country and state as well. Please guide me to get it.

Here my form fields

```
    <select id="country" name="country" ng-model="user.country" ng-options="country for (country, states) in countries" ng-change="GetSelectedCountry()" ng-required ="true">
              <option value="" disabled selected>-- Select Country --</option>
             </select>

    <select id="state" name="state" ng-disabled="!user.country" ng-model="user.state" ng-options="state for (state,city) in user.country track by state.value" ng-change="GetSelectedState()" ng-required ="true">
              <option value="" disabled selected>-- Select State --</option>
            </select>

    <select id="city" name="city" ng-disabled="!user.country || !user.state" ng-model="user.city" ng-options="city for city in user.state" ng-required ="true">
            <option value="" disabled selected>-- Select City --</option>
</select>
```

Here my angular.js code

```
$scope.countries = {
    'India': {
        'Maharashtra': ['Pune', 'Mumbai', 'Nagpur', 'Akola'],
        'Madhya Pradesh': ['Indore', 'Bhopal', 'Jabalpur'],
        'Rajasthan': ['Jaipur', 'Ajmer', 'Jodhpur']
    },
    'USA': {
      'Alabama': ['Montgomery', 'Birmingham'],
      'California': ['Sacramento', 'Fremont'],
      'Illinois': ['Springfield', 'Chicago']
    },
    'Australia': {
      'New South Wales': ['Sydney'],
      'Victoria': ['Melbourne']
    }
  };

  $scope.GetSelectedCountry = function() {
    $scope.strCountry = $scope.user.country;
  };
  $scope.GetSelectedState = function() {
    $scope.strState = $scope.user.state;
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this using ng-repeat (which in that case is more clear):

```
<select id="country" name="country" ng-model="user.country" ng-change="onCountryChange()" ng-required="true">
    <option value="" disabled selected>-- Select Country --</option>
    <option ng-repeat="(key,value) in countries" value="{{key}}">{{key}}</option>
</select>
```

Check the entrire working demo here: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r7kejodq/36/)

Comment: Thank you so much bro. You made my day.

Comment: Sure, but i can't. I have less reputation!